# iframe xss protection different domains

Tags: php, javascript, html, xss

A couple of days ago I found this website: http://hsmaker.com/
I noticed it works for any http website (i checked about 50 common websites).
It fetches the url's content into an iframe and then, I assume, it manipulates the DOM objects adding some js motion effects.

I want to do the same thing (an application a little bit more useful) but shouldn't this behavior be somehow forbidden? 
I mean I have already tried before to manipulate dom objects but, the following code does not work for me (but he can fetch http google.com - NOT https):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe style="width:100%; height:800px;" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S. Does the whole story changes if the target website is on https ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hsmaker.com is not using a iframe, they are acting as a proxy.

the reason why a website like google doesn't work in a iframe is because they have `x-frame-option` set to `forbidden`.

and no it could still work even with https.